# How to test SDK?

Tags: testing, sdk

I had an interview with mobile advertise and video company. Their product is to provide SDK to customers like CNN, AOL, etc. They asked me "How to test a SDK?" But I hardly know how to do it? I also searched online but find no answer.

Could some experience engineer help with this question? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the common way to test an SDK is building a sample app that uses the SDK (specific functionalities or all of them) in the required programming language.
Then, you can basically run the app manually, or automatically whenever the SDK updates. that way you can also test backward compatibility.